# Proof of equality between two simple expressions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sure this is really simple but why does:

$n - (\frac{n-1}{2})$ = $\frac{n+1}{2}$

Apologies if this too trivial for the particular stack exchange site.

Comment: Because $n = \frac{2n}{2}$ and $2n - (n-1) = n+1$.

Comment: I wonder if you forgot to distribute the minus sign properly to that numerator $n-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You find a common denominator, in this case $2$, and then you can subtract.

$n - \frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{2n}{2} - \frac{n-1}{2}  = \frac{2n - n + 1}{2} = \frac{n + 1}{2}$